# python how to exit a while loop and continue the parent loop?

Tags: python-3.3

when my code exits this while loop and if statement :

```
if im.getpixel((258,375)) == (30,37,43):
    battle = True
    print('lets Battle!!')
    time.sleep(10)
    leftClick()
    while battle == True:
        mousePos(503,487)
        leftClick()
        leftClick()
        time.sleep(5)
        im = screenGrab()
        if im.getpixel((258,375)) != (30,37,43) and im.getpixel((258,375)) != (99, 114, 121) and im.getpixel((258,375)) != (225, 225, 225):
            battle = False
            break
    print('battle Over')
    break
```

The code ends the parent while loop:

```
while 1 == 1:
    im = screenGrab()
    if im.getpixel((258,375)) == (30,37,43):
        battle = True
        print('lets Battle!!')
        time.sleep(10)
        leftClick()
        while battle == True:
            mousePos(503,487)
            leftClick()
            leftClick()
            time.sleep(5)
            im = screenGrab()
            if im.getpixel((258,375)) != (30,37,43) and   im.getpixel((258,375)) != (99, 114, 121) and im.getpixel((258,375)) != (225, 225, 225):
                battle = False
                break
        print('battle Over')
        break
    left(2)
    right(2)
```

I have been trying for ages but I can't get left() and right() to run and the loop to continue after the if statement ends.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `break`after your `print`statement :

```
print('battle Over')
        break
```

Your first `break`statement exits the second `while` and the `break`mentioned above exits your first `while`.

Simply remove the `break`statement if you do not want to exit the parent `while` after the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Break exits the current loop(while or for) not 'if' or 'else'. Use 'continue' to break the current iteration. And your code has 2 breaks remove the outer break and it should work as expected.